# Cannot download video file with android emulator

Tags: android, video, 3gp

Here's the code to download a 3pg video file. Maybe one can give me an idea about what's wrong with it. I really need help. Can't get it to download the file:

> Blockquote

```
        protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int count = 0;
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            BufferedOutputStream output = null;
            try {
            URL url= new URL(sUrl[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            Log.v("URL"," " + connection.getURL());
            Log.v("File ", "length = " + connection.getContentLength());
            // download the file
            BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/twokids.3gp");
            f.setWritable(true,true);
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
                    fnfe.getStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException se) {
                    se.getStackTrace();
                }

                output = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);                                                                                                                        

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                Log.v("Count="," " + count);
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
            Log.v("Download","Finished");
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException iobe) {
            iobe.getStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.getStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            npe.getStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
            }

        return null;
    }
```

And strangely enough, *sometimes* the method connection.getContentLength() returns -1 instead of the file length.

Comment: And this code works on your device? Sorry for this question, but you eventually learn not to be sure in anything here :)

Comment: I only tried this code with the emulator. I don't have the real android device.

Comment: Did you set your permissions for using network? Check your URL whether is proper. If you have an error post a stacktrace.

Comment: Yes, I have the permission set for network in the manifest file. The URL is correct. (It starts downloading but stops after about downloading about 9K of the file.) I can download the file directly from that URL, but not with the android code.

Comment: I only get this error:    05-25 04:31:57.434: E/Trace(1445): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    05-25 04:32:01.254: D/dalvikvm(1445): GC_CONCURRENT freed 137K, 10% free 2681K/2952K, paused 4ms+140ms, total 422ms
    05-25 04:32:01.254: D/dalvikvm(1445): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 362ms
    05-25 04:32:01.464: D/dalvikvm(1445): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 260K, 17% free 2725K/3264K, paused 117ms, total 163ms
    05-25 04:32:01.773: D/dalvikvm(1445): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 171K, 15% free 2858K/3332K, paused 137ms, total 188ms    It refers to an existing file. Sorry for formatting

Comment: I tried the code on a real Android device, and it worked. I guess the emulators are not reliable.